# Create stored procedure in Oracle with Roles privileges

Tags: oracle

I have a problem with creating a stored procedure.

I have permissions to the table XYZ through Roles, so when I do a SELECT to the table XYZ I don't have problem, but when I want to create a stored procedure (inside my code I call to the table XYZ table) Oracle tell me:

> Table or view doesn't exist.

When another user who have directly permissions for table XYZ create the stored procedure with the same code don't have problems.

So I hope you could help me. I think I need to assign another kind of permission to the Role that I use.

Comment: What version of Oracle are you using?

Comment: I'm using Oracle 12

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only have 2 solutions:

1. either your Oracle user is granted the direct privilege on the table (ie without a role)
2. or you create a stored procedure with invoker rights.

Here is an example of invoker right procedure.

Use `AUTHID CURRENT_USER` clause and access table `SCHEMA.XYZ` with dynamic SQL because invoker rights are not enabled at PL/SQL compilation time but only at PL/SQL run time.

```
create or replace procedure myproc 
authid current_user 
as
 l number;
begin
 execute immediate 'select c from schema.xyz where rownum = 1' into l;
 dbms_output.put_line('l= ' || l);
end;
/
```

Comment: For solution 2, how can I create a Stored Procedure with invoker rights?

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/dbseg/configuring-privilege-and-role-authorization.html#GUID-5E53BE5C-332A-4688-84DF-31D402C73C1C):

> **How Roles Work in PL/SQL Blocks**
>
> Role behavior in a PL/SQL block is determined by the type of block and
>   by definer's rights or invoker's rights.
>
> **Roles Used in Named Blocks with Definer's Rights**
>
> *All roles are disabled in any named PL/SQL block that executes with
>   definer's rights.*
>
> **Roles Used in Named Blocks with Invoker's Rights and Anonymous PL/SQL
>   Blocks**
>
> Named PL/SQL blocks that execute with invoker's rights and anonymous
>   PL/SQL blocks are executed based on privileges granted through enabled
>   roles.
>
> **Roles Used in Named Blocks with Definer's Rights**
>
> All roles are disabled in any named PL/SQL block that executes with
>   definer's rights.
>
> Examples of named PL/SQL blocks are stored procedures, functions, and
>   triggers.
>
> Roles are not used for privilege checking and you cannot set roles
>   within a definer's rights procedure.

This is from the 19c documentation, but it has been true pretty much forever.